# Finding iPhone which is on silent

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I have an iPhone 5 on silent in my room (somewhere). iCloud's Find My iPhone feature obviously will show me that the phone is in my building.

Is there any other way I can try to find it? Is there an alarm, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iCloud's "play a sound" feature will ding even with the phone on silent.

Comment: It will even play maximum volume regardless of the volume setting on the phone.

Comment: I genuinely didn't know about this feature. Thanks everyone!